# How to parse large xml file with Dom Parser in Android

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse large xml with Dom parser in android.The xml file size exceed 1Mb
I'm using this code,

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();        
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(istream); // normalize text representation
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
```

i got an out of memory exception, at

`Document doc = docBuilder.parse(istream);` //this line

Is there any way to cope with this issue , I'm working on android eclipse emulator.
 Any help in this regards greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Maybe use SAX instead of DOM? It is event-based and doesn't build huge in-memory structures.

Comment: I do thing the same as weekens says. Use sax parser instead